# Can a Django application authenticate with MySQL using its linux user?

Tags: python, mysql, django

The company I work for is starting development of a Django business application that will use MySQL as the database engine. I'm looking for a way to keep from having database credentials stored in a plain-text config file.

I'm coming from a Windows/IIS background where a vhost can impersonate an existing Windows/AD user, and then use those credentials to authenticate with MS SQL Server.

As an example: If the Django application is running with apache2+mod_python on an Ubuntu server, would it be sane to add a "www-data" user to MySQL and then let MySQL verify the credentials using its PAM module?

Hopefully some of that makes sense. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

MySQL controls access to tables from its own list of users, so it's better to create MySQL users with permissions.  You might want to create roles instead of users so you don't have as many to manage: an Admin, a read/write role, a read-only role, etc.

A Django application always runs as the web server user.  You could change that to "impersonate" an Ubuntu user, but what if that user is deleted?  Leave it as "www-data" and manage the database role that way.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. Normally, as I'm sure you know, you'd specify a username and password for the application to use to authenticate with the database engine in a configuration file. But I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: What else can Django use?  It only knows its own user name (www-data) and the information in `settings.py`.

Comment: Ok, so I'm assuming then that if I were to leave the database username and password blank in a Django config file it would be trying to authenticate as a blank user with a blank password? Or would it try to authenticate as www-data? I'll be doing some testing on my own, but of course some insight from people with experience will be helpful.

Comment: Django doesn't assume anything -- it uses the values in the settings.py file.  Create a MySQL user (maybe named 'django'?) with a password, and put the username and password into settings.py.